# Converting from normal date to unix epoch date in MS Access SQL query

Tags: sql, time, odbc, ms-access-2007, epoch

I'm trying to write a query for an MS Access 2007 connection to a MySQL database through ODBC. Everything's working fine, and the query does what I want it to do. The part that I'm hung up on is that I'm stuck asking the user for unix epoch time, instead of a regular date.

I looked up a bunch of references for MS Access, and while there are a number of date conversion functions I can use in the SQL call, I can't find any that I can use to convert from a normal date -> unix epoch date.

What I would like, and I assume this works, is to ask the user for the date in a much kinder fashion (a human readable date), and then convert it into unix epoch date. Now that I think about it, I guess my other option is to convert the unix epoch dates in the database after drawing them out with the SQL query, but I'd rather convert the user's input if at all possible as there is less of that input so I wouldn't have to do as much work.

```
SELECT TOP 5 Count( * ) AS [Number of visits by language], login.lang AS [Language]
FROM login, reservations, reservation_users
WHERE (reservations.start_date Between [Starting unix epoch time] And [Ending unix epoch time]) And reservations.is_blackout=0 And reservation_users.memberid=login.memberid And reservation_users.resid=reservations.resid And reservation_users.invited=0
GROUP BY login.lang
ORDER BY Count( * ) DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is going to work (don't have Access to confirm), but try the suggestion from here:

- http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/13/format-date-sql-server.aspx

which is to use:

```
    DATEDIFF(second, '1 Jan 1970', tbl.LastChangeDate)
```

This is from some of the comments.

EDIT: See the comment from Remou.

Comment: I think you mean  DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", time_field) -- http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks guys! I found this function, but didn't think to use it in the manner prescribed.

Answer (score 0):

Using MS 2010 I found this works: DateAdd("s",([epoch timestamp]-21600),#1/1/1970#)

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/convert-epoch-date-t2324318.html